# A space homeomorphic to its own power

Tags: general-topology, limits-colimits

I sought for a topological space that is homeomorphic to its own power, e.g. $X \cong 2^X$ for the discrete two-point space $2$. Of course, $2^X$ has the compact-open topology.

Here's my approach: First I probed its underlying set. Simple argument; treat the base $2$ as the power set operation. That is, let $X_0 = \emptyset$, let $X_{k+1} = \mathcal{P}(X_k)$, and take the categorical direct limit, where the morphism $f_{k, k+1} : X_k \to X_{k+1}$ is given as $f_{k, k+1}(x) = \{x\}$. That gives $X = \emptyset \cup \mathcal{P}(\emptyset) \cup \mathcal{P}^2(\emptyset) \cup \mathcal{P}^3(\emptyset) \cup \cdots$, resulting in some countably infinite set.

But that doesn't give any information about the topological structure of $X$. I tried probing some topological properties of $X$, and concluded that $X$ is:

- zero-dimensional Hausdorff
- not discrete
- not compact
- locally compact (proved using Ascoli's theorem)

How can I explicitly identify the topology of $X$? A subbasis would suffice, as long as it doesn't involve circular reasoning.

Comment: Homeomorphic spaces have the same cardinality but $X$ and $2^X$ never have the same cardinality.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Not quite under the category of topological spaces. Consider the one-point compactification $\overline{\omega}$ of the ordinal $\omega$. Then $2^{\overline{\omega}}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: ???? Explain how there can be a bijection from the uncountable space $2^{\omega +1}$ to the countable space $\Bbb Z.$

Comment: The colimit you describe is discrete since each $X_k$ is discrete.  Note that the functor $2^{-}$ does not send colimits to colimits (indeed, it is contravariant, so you could only expect it to maybe send colimits to *limits*) so there is no reason to expect your space to satisfy $X\cong 2^X$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: By $2^X$ he means the space of continuous maps $X\to 2$.

Comment: Domain theory deals with these recursive equations (mainly over lattice/order/topological structures), you may be interested in that. For example it famously gave a model of lambda calculus, where $\Lambda \cong \Lambda^\Lambda$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Note that $2^{\bar\omega}$ is countable, because its points are clopen subsets of $\bar\omega$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You are using some non-standard notation.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Please have a look at [compact-open topology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology). Also, the notation is quite standard for exponential objects.

Comment: The standard notation, which you will find in any text on set theory or topology, is that $2^X$ is the set of all functions from $X$ to $2=\{0,1\}$ or the cardinal of this set or the set of all subsets of $X$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That is not very helpful because (1) OP has made the definition very clear, and (2) it *is* standard notation for $Y^X$ to be the exponential object, despite your multiple claims in the contrary.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet the notation $Y^X$ for the space of continuous functions $f:X\to Y$ is used in e.g. Dugundji's Topology. So it's not true that any standard topology text uses different notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such space, by the [Lawvere fixed point theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere%27s+fixed+point+theorem), because there is a map $2 \to 2$ with no fixed points. ($\text{Top}$ is not a cartesian closed category but the proof only requires that the specific exponential used in the argument exists, and in fact it only requires that continuous maps $X \to 2^X$ can be identified with continuous maps $X \times X \to 2$. I am assuming that your use of the notation $2^X$ implies that this holds.)

Comment: Well this is... shocking. Does this mean there are some values of Haskell's `newtype PredFix = PredFix {appPredFix :: PredFix -> Bool}` that are bottom? That was how I was motivated for this question.

Comment: I don't know what that notation means in category-theoretic terms. The closest thing I can think of is the construction of the initial algebra of an endofunctor via iterating that endofunctor (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/initial+algebra+of+an+endofunctor). But that construction requires a *covariant* functor, and one that preserves certain colimits (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Ad%C3%A1mek%27s+fixed+point+theorem).

Comment: Of course $2^-$ is contravariant, but it can be composed with itself to yield the covariant functor $2^{2^-}$. In Haskell, this is the monad `Cont Bool`.

Comment: @DannyuNDos You can try replacing $2$ with $V$, the three point five opens topological space, which contains a bottom and satisfy the fixpoint property.

Comment: @Trebor What about replacing $2$ with the ordinal $\omega + 1$ in the order topology? I have trouble thinking with non-Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: Let's be precise here. You're saying that there is no such compactly generated weakly Hausdorff space? So if what @DannyuNDos says in his question that $X$ must be locally compact Hausdorff, is true, then doesn't that refute every topological space?

Comment: @Jakobian: I am saying that there is no such space $X$ in any category of topological spaces in which the exponential $2^X$ exists. I'm not familiar enough with exponentiability to know exactly how strong this condition is.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan look at the page four of [this article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/StricklandCGHWSpaces.pdf) for reference. The category of compactly generated weakly Hausdorff spaces is Cartesian closed, the exponential object exists, and coincides (at least when $X$ is Hausdorff) with the space of continuous functions $X\to Y$ with compact-open topology.

Comment: Sure, in that case it follows that $X$ can't be compactly generated Hausdorff.